# node streams not working inside lambda handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I want to simply stream content in a lambda to a S3 bucket.

I use a fork of this project to do so : https://github.com/lubos/aws-lambda-wkhtmltopdf

Problem is, the file in the bucket is created but without any content.

I started testing locally with `local-node-lambda` https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-node-lambda to understand what's wrong.

Thing is the read stream doesn't seem to ouput anything when in the lambda context.

I did a quick test :

With a simple example `test.js` :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var rstream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/input.txt');
rstream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

`node test.js` is outputting content of the input file as expected.

But if i create a lambda `index.js` :

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var rstream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/input.txt');
  rstream.pipe(process.stdout);
}
```

with `local-node-lambda -p index.js` nothing is output.

I tried several different things, with read and write streams, nothing is read or written from inside the handler, no matter what.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: wich is the node version?

Comment: on local tests, node 6.2